# Killing Ubuntu window in WSL

Tags: kill

I'm totally new to Ubuntu so please forgive this *newbie* question:
I just installed Ubuntu to run under Windows 10 and was playing around with some commands. The "wifi" command, however, seemed to hang up my Bash Shell. What is the easiest (and cleanest) way to kill it?
Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (also the keyboard shortcut for copying something) should do the trick.